# How do the event callbacks relate to the Codename One UIBuilder lifecycle?

Tags: codenameone

I have created a resource using the Codename One Designer tool, but want to programatically change the preferred width of a component before layout of its container is performed.

In which event handler am I supposed to put this code?

Or stated more general: How do the event callbacks fit into the lifecycle of creating components from a resource file?

Answer (score 0):

The before method can be used to intercept such callback. Just click before show in the events section and do whatever you want to the UI. No need to revalidate at this point since it is invoked before the UI is actually shown.